# Refactoring hapi configs with joi validation

Tags: javascript, rest, validation, refactoring, hapi.js

I have hapi routes configs, which contains validation and I want to move this validation from config to file with validations for this model. For example for PATCH for users:

```
const routeConfig = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  path: '/users/{id}',
  config: {
    ...
    validate: {
      params: {
        id: Joi.string().required()
      },
      payload: {
        email: Joi.string().email().optional(),
        password: Joi.string().optional(),
        fieldA: Joi.string().optional(),
        fieldB: {
          fieldB1: Joi.string().optional(),
          fieldB2: Joi.string().optional(),
          fieldB3: Joi.string().uri().optional(),
          fieldB4: Joi.string().uri().optional(),
          fieldB5: {
            fieldB6: Joi.string().optional(),
            fieldB7: Joi.string().optional(),
            fieldB8: Joi.string().optional()
          }
        }
      }
    },
    handler
  }
}
```

On POST:

```
const routeConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/users',
  config: {
    ...
    validate: {
      email: Joi.string().email().required(),
      password: Joi.string().required(),
      confirmPassword: Joi.string().required()
    },
    handler
  }
}
```

How you can see, for create and update used different fields.
Also, I have routes, which related to another model, like this:

```
const routeConfig = {
  method: 'PUT',
  path: '/users/{id}/updateRelated',
  config: {
    validate: {
      params: {
        id: Joi.string().required()
      },
      payload: {
        relatedId: Joi.string().required(),
        relatedModelFieldA: Joi.string().required(),
        relatedModelFieldB: Joi.string().required(),
        relatedModelFieldC: Joi.string().required(),
        ... 10 fields
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only for model I can move to validator with structure:

```
const validationSchemas = {
  'post-users': {
    payload: ...
  }
  'patch-users': {
    params: ...,
    payload: ...
  },
  ...
}
```

But how include related routes? Because payload for PUT updateRelated is equivalent to PUT on this related models(ex: PUT /users/{user_id}/modelA equivalent PUT /modelA/{modelA_id})

Also, another endpoint can receive data for user model. For example: /me/coords can update coords field in user model, where payload will contain only latitude and longitude types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an export for your Id validation which would be common across multiple routes like

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = Joi.object({
   id: Joi.string().required()
});
```

Then for each of your different payload validations create an export of for it. i.e.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email().optional(),
    password: Joi.string().optional(),
    fieldA: Joi.string().optional(),
    fieldB: {
      fieldB1: Joi.string().optional(),
      fieldB2: Joi.string().optional(),
      fieldB3: Joi.string().uri().optional(),
      fieldB4: Joi.string().uri().optional(),
      fieldB5: {
        fieldB6: Joi.string().optional(),
        fieldB7: Joi.string().optional(),
        fieldB8: Joi.string().optional()
      }
    }
});
```

Then require them in your route and use them as part of the validate object. i.e.

```
const idParamsSchema = require('./id-param-schema');
const payloadSchema = require('./payload-schema');

...

const routeConfig = {
  method: 'PUT',
  path: '/users/{id}/updateRelated',
  config: {
     validate: {
        params: idParamsSchema,
        payload: payloadSchema
     }
  }
}
```